# SpringBoot app not communicating with kafka broker when both are hosted on docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, spring-kafka

I have a springboot application which is using kafka consumer and producer. I hosted my application image on docker.Kafka server runs fine on docker but my application is not communicating with that hosted server.Sharing all the config file. Please let me know where I am going wrong

Kafka config in springboot

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, UpdateStatusObject> consumerFactory() {

        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        config.put(JsonSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, "up:com.moviebookingapp.models.UpdateStatusObject");
        config.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE, "com.moviebookingapp.models.UpdateStatusObject");
        config.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, UpdateStatusObject>(config, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(UpdateStatusObject.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, UpdateStatusObject> kafkaLister() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, UpdateStatusObject> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

        factory.setMissingTopicsFatal(false);

        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, UpdateStatusObject> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka:9092");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        config.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);
        config.put(JsonSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, "up:com.moviebookingapp.models.UpdateStatusObject");

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
    }


    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, UpdateStatusObject> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

}
```

Kafka topic config

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfig {

    @Bean
    public NewTopic ticketAvailabilityTopic() {
        return new NewTopic("ticket-availability-topic", 1, (short) 1);
    }

}
```

Docker compose file

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: moviebookingappmongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest
    container_name: moviebookingappzookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    container_name: moviebookingappkafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

  moviebookingappspringboot:
    image: moviebookingapp:1.0
    container_name: moviebookingappspringboot
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092

    links:
      - mongodb
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
```

Error

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group_id-1, groupId=group_id] Node -1 disconnected.
WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group_id-1, groupId=group_id] Connection to node -1 (kafka/172.27.0.4:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group_id-1, groupId=group_id] Bootstrap broker kafka:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

Comment: In Docker world, 127.0.0.1 (or localhost) means "the current container in which I am actually running". So you are trying to contact a bootstrap server on port 9092 on the same container where your springboot app is running (and where it does obviously not exist). Regarding your try configuring this correctly using the service name (i.e. `kafka:9092`), [can you elaborate on `I got error while creating an image out of it`](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)? Please do not reply in comments, [edit] your question.

Comment: Changed to kafka and was able to create an image but now new error is there - updated the question

Comment: You still have localhost in your configuration for listeners configuration. One thing you might want to check if it still fails is if your kafka container is up and running before your app starts.

Comment: The advertised listeners are what clients use to connect. Those cannot be localhost for other containers to connect